# Keep autolayout contraints after changing superview in the storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, storyboard, autolayout

I have a UIView in the storyboard where all the constraints are defined. Now I have to change it so that all the subviews are inside a new scroll view. I drag a scroll view into the view, adjust the size and then add all the subviews into the scroll view. All the autolayout constraints are now out of place and the best solution I find is to delete the constraints and create them again, but this is very time consuming. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to transfer the constraints. You can take a look at [this article](http://indiestack.com/2013/12/transplanting-constraints/) that shows how to edit your storyboard in a text editor.

One thing that can at least help a little bit is the "Embed In" functionality. This will wrap a container around your *selected* child views and at least save you the time of repositioning everything.

Editor > Embed In > Scroll View

[image: EmbedIn]